# JPA Entities: how to check recursive parents

Tags: java, jpa-2.1

I have a simple entity representing a group.

```
 public class Group {
 Long id;
 String name;

 @JoinColumn(name = "idparent", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "ID")
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Group.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {}, optional = true)
 private Group parent;
 }
```

A group can be the parent of some groups.

During tests I set `A.parent = A`, so the A object fall in recursion.

Is there an annotation or something to check the following constraint?

```
a.id != a.parent.id
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom jpa validation in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878992/custom-jpa-validation-in-spring-boot), also see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator)

Comment: @dan1st Hi. It helped me but my problem is a bit more difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom validator and class level annotation constraint, bind a  validator class using the Constraint annotation of validation api.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = GroupConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface GroupConstraint {
        String message() default "Invalid TestA.";
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Create the validator class with the validation logic to check `a.id != a.parent.id`

```
public class GroupConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<GroupConstraint, Group>{

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Group object, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         if (!(object instanceof Group)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("@CustomConstraint only applies to TestA");
            }
         Group group = (Group) object;
         if (group.getParent() != null && group.getParent().getId() == group.getId()) {
             return false; 
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

Apply this constraint to the entity class, Group.

```
@Entity
@GroupConstraint
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "ID",unique = true)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "IDPARENT", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Group.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {}, optional = true)
    private Group parent;
```

Now the validation provider should through a constraint violation during lifecycle callbacks , that is when child references itself.

```
Group child = new Group();
//set attributes
child.setParent(child);
em.persist(child);
```

Comment: It solve my problem. I've used a bit of reflection and interfaces to create a generick "checkparentvalidator"