# How to add validation checks spanning multiple fields in a JPA entity

Tags: java, validation, jpa

How to add validation checks spanning multiple fields in a JPA entity. If birthDate is present, then deathDate should be higher than birthDate. How do I enforce it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    private Date birthDate;

    private Date deathDate;

}
```

Comment: where do you want to apply those checks ?

Comment: It depends on what and how you want to validate but if you're using Hibernate the accepted answer of this question would probably be ideal to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878992/custom-jpa-validation-in-spring-boot

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve this, without relying on the underlying persistence provider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate two or more fields in combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781771/how-can-i-validate-two-or-more-fields-in-combination)